# How to figure out if no association with other tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables: tags, place_tags, event_tags

tags:

```
---------------------
|  tag_id  |  name  |
---------------------
|    1     |  cat   |
---------------------
|    2     |  dog   |
---------------------
|    3     |  fish  |
---------------------
```

place_tags:

```
-------------------------
|  place_id  |  tag_id  |
-------------------------
|      1     |     1    |
-------------------------
|      2     |     2    |
-------------------------
|      3     |     1    |
-------------------------
```

event_tags:

```
-------------------------
|  event_id  |  tag_id  |
-------------------------
|      1     |     1    |
-------------------------
|      2     |     2    |
-------------------------
|      3     |     1    |
-------------------------
```

I am trying to write a query that will look at all the tags in the `tags` table and will find which of them are not associated with either of the other tables. In this example, you can see that `tag_id 3` is not used in any other table, so I want to select it and output it.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tag
where not exists (select * from place_tags where tag_id = tag.tag_id)
and not exists (select * from event_tags where tag_id = tag.tag_id)
```

Or more efficient, but perhaps harder to read:

```
select * from tag
where tag_id not in (
    select tag_id from place_tags where tag_id is not null
    union
    select tag_id from event_tags where tag_id is not null)
```

Note: the `where tag_id is not null` is needed because if one of the rows has a `tag_id` of `null`, the `in` will always be `false`.

Comment: The second query is *less* efficient than the first, because it selects *every single row* from *both tables*, and it does this while going through *every row* in the tags table. If you have anything more than a few rows, it will be terribly slow.

Comment: @Radu Unfortunately you are wrong about the relative efficiencies: The first query will make **one query against place_tags and event_tags FOR EVERY ROW in tag** (they are called "correlated subqueries") - although they are potentially indexed queries. The second option only make 2 queries against place_tags and event_tags, although they will be table scans (indexes won't be used for null lookups). EG, even if there are only 100 rows in tag, two tables scans will always be faster than 200 separate queries. Imagine if there are 1 million rows!

Comment: @Bohemian, it would be fortunate to be wrong, that would mean the OP is now using the right thing. However, I will have to point you to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subquery-restrictions.html) again, especially the part in which it explains how an `IN` subquery is translated in a correlated query. I do agree with you though that both examples are extremely sub-optimal.

Comment: @Radu Do you still think option 1 (2n queries, where n is row count in tags) is faster than option 2 (2 queries)?

Comment: @Bohemian, option 2 does *not* run just 2 queries. Please read the documentation from the link. The `IN()` call makes those 2 queries execute *every time*, just like in the first example.

Comment: @Radu. Holy crap. Emphasis on the **crap**. MySql has some very funky non-standard features, but it also has some rubbish under the covers. OK. I learned something else!. BTW, I've found that using a view to gather the IDs up works to keep it a simple one-shot subquery.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient, index-using, single-`SELECT`, `JOIN`-based query could be:

```
   SELECT tags.*
     FROM tags
LEFT JOIN place_tags ON place_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
LEFT JOIN event_tags ON event_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
    WHERE place_tags.tag_id IS NULL AND
          event_tags.tag_id IS NULL
```

This joins the tables you're looking into and only selects the tags that have no correspondence in either of them.

Comment: It won't work because you have place_tags.tag_id IS NULL in your where clause - there are no such rows. You can't find missing join rows like that.

Comment: @Bohemian, of course it will work. Please check the documentation and run the query.

Comment: I did test it, and you are correct! (This style of query once upon a time didn't work, but clearly now it does. I learned something). If you want the -1 removed, you'll have to edit your answer :)

Comment: @Bohemian, actually this is how I did these kinds of things since the first time I stumbled upon this situation (which was a long time ago). Thank you for removing the -1.